# How do I get the dependencies tree to show in a stackblitz node.js new project?

Tags: dependencies, stackblitz

I started this up to get a terminal window in my project, but there is no dependencies tree...

https://stackblitz.com/fork/nextjs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788506/stackblitz-no-longer-showing-dependencies. I don't fully understand it myself right now but you'll probably find you have a terminal windows where you can run update commands.