# StackBlitz no longer showing dependencies?

Tags: javascript, html, stackblitz

How can I show the dependencies panel in this StackBlitz?
[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cudle8-rqwfxp

I notice some projects it shows but newer ones it does not.

Comment: It depends on the project type. Full-stack/Backend projects have a terminal and full control. Frontend projects have the dependencies panel and more things are automatic (the lack of a terminal can be painful).